# Devolver el número de elementos de una propiedad en javascript

Tags: javascript

```
     getMascotas() {
         // El método 'getMascotas' debe retornar la cantidad de mascotas que tiene el emprendedor.
         // Ej:
         // Suponiendo que el emprendedor tiene estas mascotas: ['perro', 'gato']
         // emprendedor.getMascotas() debería devolver 2
    
         // Tu código aca:
              
            return this.mascotas.map(mascotas => mascotas.lenght)  
     }
```

No puedo hacer que solo retorne el número de mascotas...

Comment: Debería ser `return this.mascotas.length`

Comment: 1. Es `length`, no `lenght`. 2. El enunciado te pide retornar la cantidad de elementos dentro del array, no la longitud de cada elemento del array. En síntesis, es lo que menciona @JaimeMenéndez en su comentario.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Emprendedor {
    constructor(nombre, mascotas) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.mascotas = mascotas;
    }
    getMascotas() {
      // return this.mascotas.length // Retornará: 2
      return `El ${this.nombre} tiene: ${this.mascotas.length} mascotas`;
    }
  } 
  const user = new Emprendedor("Usuario", ["perro", "gato"]);
  console.log(user.getMascotas());
```

No necesitas hacer un recorrido, 'mascotas' es un array por lo cual ya tiene la propiedad .length para obtener el valor que deseas.